# drop rows from a pandas dataframe based on list of points in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have two dataframes:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.repeat(np.arange(1.,11.),50), 
                    "B": np.tile(np.repeat(np.arange(0.,5.),10),10), 
                    "C":np.arange(500)})
bad_data = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1., 2., 7., 9.], 
                           "B": [0., 3., 0., 2.], 
                           "points": [[0, 1],[0],[1],[0,1]]})
data.head(15)
bad_data
>>> data.head(15)
      A    B   C
0   1.0  0.0   0
1   1.0  0.0   1
2   1.0  0.0   2
3   1.0  0.0   3
4   1.0  0.0   4
5   1.0  0.0   5
6   1.0  0.0   6
7   1.0  0.0   7
8   1.0  0.0   8
9   1.0  0.0   9
10  1.0  1.0  10
11  1.0  1.0  11
12  1.0  1.0  12
13  1.0  1.0  13
14  1.0  1.0  14
>>> bad_data
     A    B  points
0  1.0  0.0  [0, 1]
1  2.0  3.0     [0]
2  7.0  0.0     [1]
3  9.0  2.0  [0, 1]
```

For each row of `data`, I want to drop all rows in `bad_data` with the same `A` and `B`, and indexed by the values of `points`. For example, the first row of `bad_data` tells me that I need to drop the first two rows of `data`:

```
      A    B   C
0   1.0  0.0   0
1   1.0  0.0   1
```

How can I do that? I was able to cook up this horror, but it's quite ugly to read. Can you help me write a more Pythonic/readable solution?

```
rows_to_remove = []
for A, B in zip(bad_data['A'], bad_data['B']):
    rows_in_data = (data['A'] == A) & (data['B'] == B)
    rows_in_bad_data = (bad_data['A'] == A) & (bad_data['B'] == B)
    bad_points = bad_data.loc[rows_in_bad_data, 'points'].values[0]
    indices = data[rows_in_data].index.values[bad_points]
    rows_to_remove.extend(indices)
    print(rows_to_remove)
data.drop(data.index[rows_to_remove], inplace=True)
```

Comment: do the values in "point" refer to  the absolute index? relative to the group? value in "C"?

Comment: @mozway They refer to the index relative to the group defined by the current values of `A` and `B`. Maybe, to avoid confusion with the values of `C`, I can define `C` as `"C":np.random.random(500)`. This way, it's obvious that `[0,1]` cannot be a subset of values of `C`. What do you think? Would that make the question more readable?

Comment: @DeltaV thanks, this is clear, I provided an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could perform a reverse merge on the exploded bad_data:

```
data2 = (data
.assign(points=data.groupby(['A', 'B']).cumcount())  # get index per group (=points)
.merge(bad_data.explode('points'), on=['A', 'B', 'points'], # outer merge
       indicator=True, how='outer')
.loc[lambda d: d['_merge'].eq('left_only')]  # keep the rows unique to the left
.drop(columns=['points', '_merge'])          # remove helper columns
)
```

Another option is to use `GroupBy.apply`:

```
# craft a Series of list of points indexed by A/B
s = bad_data.set_index(['A', 'B'])['points']
    # group by A/B
data2 = (data
     .groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False, group_keys=False)
     # get the real index names from "index" and drop if the key is present in s
     # else leave the group unchanged
     .apply(lambda g: g.drop(g.index[s.loc[g.name]]) if g.name in s else g)
)
```

Both approaches yield the same dataframe as your custom code.

output shape:

```
data2.shape
# (494, 3)
```

---

Details on second solution:

- craft a Series `s` to be like:

```
A    B  
1.0  0.0    [0, 1]
2.0  3.0       [0]
7.0  0.0       [1]
9.0  2.0    [0, 1]
Name: points, dtype: object
```

- make groups by A/B
- for each group, if it is present in the index of `s` (the key is `g.name`), fetch the values `s.loc[g.name]`, get the matching indices from the relative position in the group: `g.index[s.loc[g.name]]`, feed this to drop. If the A/B index is absent, return the group unchanged.

Comment: @DeltaIV yes, it should be `data`, my bad, the habit of using `df`, let me have a look at your update

Comment: @DeltaIV I see the "issue", my solutions are not **in place**, you need to assign the output. I made this explicit ;)

Comment: this is useful. Would it be possible for you to also show, optionally, how to make the modifications in place? Or would "inplacing" require too much modifications to your code? Is  "inplacing" frowned upon as a bad practice? It would seem very convenient to me.

Comment: Most "`inplace`" function are actually not in place and use copies. There is an [active discussion](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529) whether or not to deprecate the `inplace` parameters in pandas. If you really need to modify "in place", you can modify my code to yield the indices to drop using `.loc[lambda d: d['_merge'].ne('left_only')].index` in place of the last 2 lines and assigning to a `idx` variable, then `data.drop(idx, inplace=True)`.

Comment: thanks, I improved my voting and accepted the answer in view of your modifications/comments. Just as a curiosity, if you find some time, it would be nice to explain a bit more in detail how the second solution works (I wasn't able to understand it!). But no hurry, the first solution works and it's pretty clear, so the answer is fine for me.

Comment: @DeltaIV I added details, hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% if I understood this correctly or my attempt is the most elegant way, so let me know if this works for you:

```
bad_indexes = []
labels = ['A', 'B']

for _, s in bad_data.iterrows():
    p = data.loc[s['points']]
    p = p[p[labels].eq(s[labels]).all(1)]
    bad_indexes.extend(p.index)

result = data.loc[data.index.difference(bad_indexes)]
```

I assumed that the index of `data` has unique values.